# Why are those statements about ideals true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

- (a) If $f\::\:R\:\rightarrow \:T$ is an epimorphism, and $I\subset R$ is an ideal, then $f\left(I\right)$ is an ideal in T
- (b) If I take an ideal $J\supset I$, and $\pi :\:R\:\rightarrow \:R/I$ is an epimorphism, then $\pi \left(J\right)$ is also an ideal
- (c) The function $\pi$ is a bijection which retains the inclusion relation
- (d) $\left\{J\supset I\::\:J\:\in Max\:R\right\}\ni L\:\rightarrow \:\pi \left(L\right)\in \:\left\{M\:\subset R/I\::\:M\:\in \:Max\:R/I\right\}$ is also a bijection which retains the inclusion relation (the same goes for Spec R and Spec R/I)
- (e) $I \in Max\:R\:\Leftrightarrow \:\pi \left(I\right)=\left(0\right)\in Max R/I \Leftrightarrow  R/I\text{ is a field}$

My approach to that is:

(a) and (b) essentially describe the same problem because we are dealing with an epimorphism and this can be proved by just writing out the properties of ideals and using the homomorphism of f and $\pi$.

What I don't understand though is (c), why should $\pi$ be a bijection if we defined it as an epimorphism which is a surjection, but no injection? Also what does it mean to "retain the inclusion relation" (that's translated from my mother tongue so maybe it's different in English)

I'd really like to see how we should prove (d), I am fairly confident that we should use the homomorphism properties of $\pi$ but how?

I kind of understand the proof of (e), because you use the fact that if I is a maximal ideal then R/I is a field, but why is $\pi \left(I\right)=\left(0\right)\in Max R/I$? That's something I don't quite see

Comment: Are you using "epimorphism" synonymously with "surjective homorphism"? Because they are not synonymous.

Comment: Really? Epimorphism = surjective homomorphism is literally the definition given to us

Comment: Epimorphism means something different in categorical terms. Mainly, $f$ is an epimorphism if whenever $gf = 0$ we have $g = 0$.

Comment: @marlasca23 Ring is not abelian

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of part (a), we need to be clear that we're referring to a surjective ring homomorphism. The term "epimorphism" generally does not mean "surjective ring homomorphism" - this is not standard terminology. But it's the OP's definition, so I'll go with it.

Just to make things clearer, I'm going to write $Im_\pi(S)$ for the image of $S$ under $\pi$ (what you're calling $\pi(S)$).

Part (c) says that $Im_\pi$ is a bijection between ideals of $R / I$ and ideals of $R$ which contain $I$. It does not say that $\pi$ itself is a bijection.

"Maintaining the inclusion relation" means that $Im_\pi(J) \subseteq Im_\pi(K)$ iff $J \subseteq K$ for all ideals $J, K$ such that $I \subseteq J$ and $I \subseteq K$.

Regarding (d), we prove it as follows:

Suppose that $L$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ and $I \subseteq L$. Then $Im_\pi(L)$ is an ideal of $R / I$. Suppose we have an ideal $Z \subseteq R / I$ such that $Im_\pi(L) \subseteq Z \subsetneq R/I$. Then we can write $Z = Im_\pi(Y)$ for some ideal $Y$ such that $I \subseteq Y$. Then we have $Im_\pi(L) \subseteq Im_\pi(Y) \subsetneq Im_\pi(R)$, and since $Im_\pi$ preserves the $\subseteq$ relation in both directions, we have $L \subseteq Y \subsetneq R$. Then $Y = L$. Then $Z = Im_\pi(L)$. Thus, we see that $Im_\pi(L)$ is a maximal ideal.

Now suppose that $L$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $I \subseteq L$, and suppose that $Im_\pi(L)$ is a maximal ideal. Suppose we have $L \subseteq K \subsetneq R$ for some ideal $K$. Then we have $Im_\pi(L) \subseteq Im_\pi(K) \subsetneq Im_\pi(R) = R / I$, since $Im_\pi$ preserves the $\subseteq$ relation and is injective. Then $Im_\pi(K) = Im_\pi(L)$, since $Im_\pi(L)$ is a maximal ideal. Then $K = L$, since $Im_\pi$ is injective.

Thus, we see that $Im_\pi$ restricts to a bijection $\{L$ a maximal ideal of $R$: $I \subseteq L\} \to \{K$ a maximal ideal of $R / I\}$. Since $Im_\pi$ preserves $\subseteq$ in both directions, so does the restriction.

For proving (d) with respect to prime ideals:

Suppose $I \subseteq L$, $L$ is a prime ideal. Now suppose we have $xy \in Im_\pi(L)$. Then we write $x = \pi(a)$, $y = \pi(b)$. Then we have $\pi(ab) \in Im_\pi(L)$. Then we can write $ab = \ell + i$ where $\ell \in L$ and $i \in I$. But we see that since $I \subseteq L$, we have $\ell + i \in L$. Then $ab \in L$. Then $a \in L$ or $b \in L$. Then $\pi(a) \in Im_\pi(L)$ or $\pi(b) \in Im_\pi(L)$. Then $Im_\pi(L)$ is prime.

Now suppose $I \subseteq L$, $L$ is an ideal, and $Im_\pi(L)$ is prime. Consider $a, b$ such that $ab \in L$. Then $\pi(a) \pi(b) \in Im_\pi(L)$. Then $\pi(a) \in Im_\pi(L)$ or $\pi(b) \in Im_\pi(L)$. WLOG, take $\pi(a) \in Im_\pi(L)$. Then we can write $\pi(a) = \pi(\ell)$ for some $\ell \in L$. Then $a = \ell + i$ for some $i \in I$. And $i \in I \subseteq L$, so $\ell + i \in L$. Then $a \in L$. Thus, $L$ is prime.

(e) follows immediately from (d). By part (d), $I$ is a maximal ideal iff $Im_\pi(I)$ is. And it's easy to show that $(0)$ is a maximal ideal of a ring exactly when the ring is a field.

Comment: Thanks. It's strange that you say that (a) is false, because it's literally a 1:1 translation and I double checked it if it's right.

Comment: @user Just saw that you're using a different definition of "epimorphism". I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: How would (d) will be proven if we take Spec R instead of Max R? So if they are prime ideals, and no maximal ideals? What I wonder in (e) is that we have that $\pi$(I) is a maximal ideal in R/I iif R/I is a field, but shouldn't it be R/I/I (does even such a thing exist?). Because I had this "theorem" that if "I is a maximal ideal in R iif R/I is a field", so if we have that it's a maximal ideal in R/I, shouldn't it be that R/I/I is a field? Sry if this sounds naive but I simply don't know if R/I/I exists or if simply R/I/I = R/I

Comment: @user Updated to prove part (d) for Spec R. You are correct that $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$ if and only if $R/I$ is a field. But note that $(R / I) / (\pi(I)) = (R / I) / (0) \simeq R / I$. So $I$ is maximal iff $R / I$ is a field iff $(R / I) / (\pi(I))$ is a field iff $\pi(I)$ is maximal.